# Why there is no hover highlighting on visited links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, hyperlinks, user-experience

Currently the visited question links are painted in darker blue and the hover effect for these links is disabled.
I suppose it so by design, but what is the idea behind it?

[image]

#### Why I like hover highlighting

Hover highlighting has positive effect in usability, namely for these reasons:

- it is a visual feedback which improves visibility of the link under mouse cursor, so
  in turn it improves the ease of the point-and-click actions.
- without this highlighting I need to make a small pause before the click, to make sure that mouse is above the correct 
  link. This is seen by the cursor changing to 'hand' but this not so visible and it is the reason why the hover effect should be there.
- currently it makes an inconsistence: [not visited - with hover] / [visited - without hover] which adds extra brain load

#### Proposal

Make ALL links WITH hover highlighting, and probably make the hover color more distinctive from the parent color.
I have tested this with Stylish user style and for me it showed better usability experience.
What do you think?